# Can't load a Java Card Applet

Tags: java, applet, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I am trying to upload a Java Card Applet onto a physical Java Card in CLI using **gp.exe**, but i still get the same error with all the cards i tried and i don't know how to fix it. But when i try with a tool like PyApduTool, it works, the applet is loaded on the card.

This is the error that i get :

```
C:\Java\Test>gp -load test.cap -d -v
GlobalPlatformPro 18.09.14-0-gb439b52
Running on Windows 10 10.0 amd64, Java 1.8.0_291 by Oracle Corporation
# Detected readers from JNA2PCSC
[ ] JAVACOS Virtual Contact Reader 0
[ ] JAVACOS Virtual Contactless Reader 1
[*] OMNIKEY AG Smart Card Reader USB 0
SCardConnect("OMNIKEY AG Smart Card Reader USB 0", T=*) -> T=0, 3B7D9400005744290830869312C09011241F
SCardBeginTransaction("OMNIKEY AG Smart Card Reader USB 0")
Reader: OMNIKEY AG Smart Card Reader USB 0
ATR: 3B7D9400005744290830869312C09011241F
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3B7D9400005744290830869312C09011241F

A>> T=0 (4+0000) 00A40400 00
A<< (0018+2) (15ms) 6F108408A000000003000000A5049F6501FF 9000
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Auto-detected ISD: A000000003000000
Warning: no keys given, using default test key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
A>> T=0 (4+0008) 80500000 08 7A168DB21C78850A 00
A<< (0000+2) (31ms) 6D00
INITIALIZE UPDATE failed: 0x6D00 (Invalid INStruction)
```

This what i get using PyApduTool

```
Select CardManager begin...
Select CardManager successful.
Download Cap begin...
Download Cap successful.
Install Applet begin...
Install Applet successful.
Select Applet begin...
Select Applet successful.
```

And this is APDU Trace after downloading the applet (Using PyApduTool) :

```
<<00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00
>>61 12

<<00 C0 00 00 12
>>6F 10 84 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 A5 04 9F 65 01 FF 90 00

<<80 50 00 00 08 1F F4 FD 4A AA 1F C4 D3 1C
>>61 1C

<<00 C0 00 00 1C
>>00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6F 02 01 73 9E 8F B9 93 D0 3E 24 9F F1 88 26 27 F5 21 90 00

<<84 82 00 00 10 75 09 52 F3 74 54 98 D3 AF 4C D6 09 B5 E7 F0 EA
>>90 00

<<80 E6 02 00 17 0A 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
>>61 01

<<00 C0 00 00 01
>>00 90 00

<<80 E8 00 00 FA C4 82 01 49 01 00 14 DE CA FF ED 01 02 04 00 01 0A 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 02 00 1F 00 14 00 1F 00 0F 00 15 00 2A 00 0C 00 81 00 0A 00 16 00 00 00 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 01 00 04 00 15 02 02 01 07 A0 00 00 00 62 01 01 00 01 07 A0 00 00 00 62 00 01 03 00 0F 01 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 00 10 06 00 0C 00 80 03 01 FF 00 07 01 00 00 00 1D 07 00 81 00 02 10 18 8C 00 01 18 03 88 00 18 8B 00 02 7A 02 30 8F 00 03 3D 8C 00 04 8B 00 02 7A 03 21 19 8B 00 05 2D 18 8B 00 06 60 03 7A 1A 03 25 10 B0 6A 08 11 6E 00 8D 00 07 1A 04 25 73 00 3F 00 00 00 03 00 0F 00 1A 00 25 00 32 18 3D 84 00 04 41 5B 88 00 70 2D 18 3D 84 00 04 43 5B 88 00 70 22 1A 03 AE 00 38 19 03 04 8B 00 08 70 15 19 8B 00 09 3B 18 1A 08 25 88 00 70 08 11 6D 00 8D 00 07 7A 01
>>61 01

<<00 C0 00 00 01
>>00 90 00

<<80 E8 80 01 53 08 00 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 2A 00 0A 02 00 00 00 06 80 03 00 03 80 03 01 01 00 00 00 06 00 00 01 03 80 0A 01 03 80 03 03 06 80 07 01 03 80 0A 08 03 80 0A 06 09 00 16 00 07 0A 43 05 06 05 06 14 00 0B 05 08 06 04 03 07 05 10 33 06 0F 01
>>61 01

<<00 C0 00 00 01
>>00 90 00
```

After installing the applet :

```
<<80 50 00 00 08 60 1A 14 C6 EF 6E 0A 92 1C
>>61 1C

<<00 C0 00 00 1C
>>00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6F 02 01 87 CB 8B 1A 33 11 80 80 11 6B D1 51 F6 D9 86 90 00

<<84 82 00 00 10 5B E8 17 C3 72 E6 16 E6 A8 FA C7 FD 23 BB 50 49
>>90 00

<<80 E6 0C 00 29 0A 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 01 00 02 C9 00 00 00
>>61 01

<<00 C0 00 00 01
>>00 90 00
```

After selecting the applet :

```
<<00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 00
>>90 00
```

The output of the command `java -Dsun.security.smartcardio.t0GetResponse=false -jar gp.jar -load test.cap -d -v`

```
C:\Java\Test>java -Dsun.security.smartcardio.t0GetResponse=false -jar gp.jar -load test.cap -d -v
GlobalPlatformPro v20.01.23-0-g5ad373b
Running on Windows 10 10.0 amd64, Java 1.8.0_301 by Oracle Corporation
# Detected readers from JNA2PCSC
[ ] JAVACOS Virtual Contact Reader 0
[ ] JAVACOS Virtual Contactless Reader 1
[*] OMNIKEY CardMan 3x21 0
SCardConnect("OMNIKEY CardMan 3x21 0", T=*) -> T=0, 3B7D9400005744290830869312C090111E1A
SCardBeginTransaction("OMNIKEY CardMan 3x21 0")
Reader: OMNIKEY CardMan 3x21 0
ATR: 3B7D9400005744290830869312C090111E1A
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3B7D9400005744290830869312C090111E1A

A>> T=0 (4+0000) 00A40400 00
A<< (0018+2) (14ms) 6F108408A000000003000000A5049F6501FF 9000
[TRACE] GPSession -  [6F]
[TRACE] GPSession -      [84] A000000003000000
[TRACE] GPSession -      [A5]
[TRACE] GPSession -          [9F65] FF
[DEBUG] GPSession - Auto-detected ISD: A000000003000000
Warning: no keys given, using default test key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
[WARN] PlaintextKeys - Don't know how to calculate KCV, defaulting to SCP02
[WARN] PlaintextKeys - Don't know how to calculate KCV, defaulting to SCP02
[WARN] PlaintextKeys - Don't know how to calculate KCV, defaulting to SCP02
[INFO] GPSession - Using card master keys: ENC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) MAC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) DEK=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 8BAF47) for null
[TRACE] GPSession - Generated host challenge: F81366069E0D1073
A>> T=0 (4+0008) 80500000 08 F81366069E0D1073 00
A<< (0000+2) (30ms) 6D00
INITIALIZE UPDATE failed: 0x6D00 (Invalid INStruction)
```

Comment: Please add the log from PyApduTool. Also mention the card type. Also which GP specification and SCP it supports. I would assume for newer GP cards the AID to use is `A000000151000000`.

Comment: @k_o_ I've the log from PyApduTool in my question. I unfortunatly don't have much information about the card, i only know that it is an Oberthur Smart Card.

Comment: @k_o_ Could you pls explain me what is AID and what is it for ?

Comment: @salomon_diei AID = Application IDentifier. This is the ID of the application you are talking to. Always when communication to a card an application must be selected. Search the gp manual if you can pass the AID I mentioned to the `gp` command.

Comment: @SalomonDiei You can test what k_o_ suggests by adding option `--sdaid A000000151000000` to GlobalPlatformPro. Please add APDU trace from PyApduTool -- it is in the "Basic APDU" tab. ((And please do not post the same question multiple times -- It won't help))

Comment: I tried, but this is the error that i get by typing  `C:\Java\Test>gp --sdaid A000000151000000` : `Could not SELECT Security Domain: 0x6A82 (Application/file not found)`

Comment: The card is an `ID-One Cosmo V7.0`

Comment: @SalomonDiei Thank you for the traces. It seems that both tools correctly select the Issuer Security Domain (with AID `A000000003000000`) and then attempt to authenticate (with INITIALIZE UPDATE command -- APDU `80500000...`). The difference is that GlobalPlatformPro fails. My bet is that this failure is caused by card not supporting GET RESPONSE command with the same CLA as the original command (that behaviour is mandated by ISO-7816, but some payment schemes (namely EMV) define it differently with CLA always equal to `00` -- have a look into ISO-7816...

Comment: ... or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36321143/5128464)). You may try running GlobalPlatformPro with java property `sun.security.smartcardio.t0GetResponse` set to `false` and check log (it should end with line similar to `A<< (0000+2) (31ms) 611C` which would confirm this theory). To run GlobalPlatformPro with this java property you need to grab `gp.jar` from the [releases page](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/releases/tag/v20.01.23) and run it as `java -Dsun.security.smartcardio.t0GetResponse=false -jar gp.jar -load test.cap -d -v` (please add this log to your question)

Comment: @vlp Thank you for anwsering, i uploaded my question with the output.